# Opensuse Leap 42.1: fastcgi-mono-server4 AOT problems

Tags: asp.net, nginx, mono, fastcgi-mono-server

I have recently upgraded my opensuse 12.2 machine to leap 42.1.

I would like to get web server going in  the form of:- nginx <> fastcgi-mono-server4 <> asp.net

I have installed and configured nginx - it appears to be working okay (tested it at a html level).

I have installed mono and xsp, and reconfigured nginx for fastcgi, but it doesn't work. My browser reports a list of unhelpful asp.net type errors.

When I start fastcgi-mono-server4 with debug logging, this is what I get:-

```
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/root/.mono/config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Image addref mscorlib[0x17a3f00] -> /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll[0x17a2fa0]: 2
**Mono: AOT: module /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.so is unusable: compiled with unsupported SIMD extensions.
Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.**
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
Mono: Assembly mscorlib[0x17a3f00] added to domain fastcgi-mono-server4.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe'.
Mono: Unloading image /usr/lib/mono/gac/fastcgi-mono-server4/3.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe [0x180e890].
Mono: Image addref fastcgi-mono-server4[0x180efe0] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/fastcgi-mono-server4/3.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe[0x17a1bf0]: 3
Mono: Assembly fastcgi-mono-server4[0x180efe0] added to domain fastcgi-mono-server4.exe, ref_count=1
**Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/fastcgi-mono-server4/3.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/fastcgi-mono-server4/3.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/fastcgi-mono-server4/3.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/fastcgi-mono-server4/fastcgi-mono-server4.config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe'.
Mono: Unloading image /usr/lib/mono/gac/fastcgi-mono-server4/3.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe [0x180f070].
**Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/fastcgi-mono-server4/3.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/fastcgi-mono-server4/3.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
Mono: Assembly Ref addref fastcgi-mono-server4[0x180efe0] -> mscorlib[0x17a3f00]: 2
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/fastcgi-mono-server4/3.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe.config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Mono.WebServer2.dll'.
Mono: Image addref Mono.WebServer2[0x1816b10] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebServer2/0.4.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.WebServer2.dll[0x1813c00]: 2
Mono: Assembly Mono.WebServer2[0x1816b10] added to domain fastcgi-mono-server4.exe, ref_count=1
**Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebServer2/0.4.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.WebServer2.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebServer2/0.4.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.WebServer2.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/Mono.WebServer2.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/Mono.WebServer2.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Mono.WebServer2.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebServer2/0.4.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.WebServer2.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/Mono.WebServer2/Mono.WebServer2.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref fastcgi-mono-server4[0x180efe0] -> Mono.WebServer2[0x1816b10]: 2
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Mono.WebServer2[0x1816b10] -> mscorlib[0x17a3f00]: 3
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Xml.dll'.
Mono: Image addref System.Xml[0x18190d0] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll[0x1818390]: 2
Mono: Assembly System.Xml[0x18190d0] added to domain fastcgi-mono-server4.exe, ref_count=1
**Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Xml.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Xml.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Xml.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Xml/System.Xml.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref fastcgi-mono-server4[0x180efe0] -> System.Xml[0x18190d0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Xml[0x18190d0] -> mscorlib[0x17a3f00]: 4
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.dll'.
Mono: Image addref System[0x1821ab0] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll[0x1820c70]: 2
Mono: Assembly System[0x1821ab0] added to domain fastcgi-mono-server4.exe, ref_count=1
**Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/System/System.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref fastcgi-mono-server4[0x180efe0] -> System[0x1821ab0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System[0x1821ab0] -> mscorlib[0x17a3f00]: 5
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Mono.WebServer2[0x1816b10] -> System[0x1821ab0]: 3
Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Xml[0x18190d0] -> System[0x1821ab0]: 4
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Mono.Security.dll'.
Mono: Image addref Mono.Security[0x1ba7920] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll[0x1ba4c60]: 2
Mono: Assembly Mono.Security[0x1ba7920] added to domain fastcgi-mono-server4.exe, ref_count=1
**Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/Mono.Security.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/Mono.Security.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Mono.Security.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Mono.Security[0x1ba7920] -> mscorlib[0x17a3f00]: 6
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Configuration.dll'.
Mono: Image addref System.Configuration[0x198bca0] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll[0x19b1f90]: 2
Mono: Assembly System.Configuration[0x198bca0] added to domain fastcgi-mono-server4.exe, ref_count=1
**Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll.so' not found: /usr/li[2016-06-02 12:33:42Z] Debug   fastcgi-mono-server4***
```

It seems that mono is not happy with the installation. Or at least the AOT module. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.
Peter

more info:-

```
    #mono -V
    Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.4 (Stable 4.0.4.1/5ab4c0d Sun Oct 25 12:51:49 UTC 2015)
    Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen

    #xsp -V
Exception caught during reading the configuration file:
System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager:get_AppSettings (): IL_0000: ret       


  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server+ApplicationSettings..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
XSP server is a sample server that hosts the ASP.NET runtime in a
minimalistic HTTP server

    #fastcgi-mono-server --version
    Unhandled Exception:
    System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Xml.XmlDocument:GetElementsByTagName (string): IL_0000: ret       


      at Mono.WebServer.ConfigurationManager.ImportSettings (System.Xml.XmlDocument doc, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collection, Boolean allowDuplicates, Boolean insertEmptyValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.WebServer.ConfigurationManager..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly asm, System.String resource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Xml.XmlDocument:GetElementsByTagName (string): IL_0000: ret       


      at Mono.WebServer.ConfigurationManager.ImportSettings (System.Xml.XmlDocument doc, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collection, Boolean allowDuplicates, Boolean insertEmptyValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.WebServer.ConfigurationManager..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly asm, System.String resource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: what version of mono and what version of xsp/monofastcgiserver are you using

Comment: that is problem right there, please edit your question to paste that exception in it

Comment: Peter, stop pasting useless comments or your question will be downvoted, I recommend you to remove all these comments and edit your question accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your advice knocte. I'm new to this site, but learning fast.

Comment: ok, now tell us how did you install mono and xsp please

Comment: I installed both via yast (KDE).

Comment: I've read in many places that the mono packages of fedora or suse are kind of not well maintained, if I were you I would try ubuntu16.04 instead to see if it fixes your problem, so that you stop chasnig your tail

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Are you suggesting that i install the mono from ubunto16.04 onto suse?

Comment: of course not, packages between distros are almost never compatible; I'm suggesting you install Ubuntu16.04 in other box and try it with the mono version that ubuntu bundles, and if it works, then open a bug in suse's bugzilla, and ditch it until their packagers fix it

Answer (score 0):

I have resovled this issue.

I installed xsp via yast & zypper several times without improvment. Finally, I tried installing directly from

https://software.opensuse.org/package/xsp

This has made the crital difference for me - fastcgi-mono-server4 no longer complains about unhandled exceptions. However, xsp still does. But given that I don't really want xsp, it doesn't worry me.

My nginx <> fast-mono-server4 <> asp.net web server is WORKING!

Now to do something clever with it...

Thanks for everyones assistance.